# Remove pages from sitemap

Tags: python, django, sitemap, django-cms, django-sitemaps

I'm using the Django Cms 2.3.5 and I was generating the sitemap like this article from the [docs](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.5/advanced/sitemap.html)

Now my question is there a easy solution to hide two pages from this sitemap because.
I have the 404 and the 500 error in my CMS integrated and I dont want that there are in the sitemap!?

Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try it this way:

Create a new class, and override the `get_url` method of `SiteMap` class

```
class CustomCMSSitemap(CMSSitemap):
    def get_urls(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(CustomCMSSitemap, self).get_urls(*args, **kwargs)
       //your code here
```

[Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py) is the source for the class `SiteMap`

Instead of adding `url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}})` into the main `urls.py`, add `url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CustomCMSSitemap}})`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove a page from the sitemap in django-cms is unpublishing it. Specially if that page is not ready yet (outputs 404 or 500 errors).

Comment: The pages are ready but I dont want them to have in my sitemap